# Maven - how to solve ojdbc7 cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file?

Tags: java, oracle, maven

I'm trying to add Oracle support to my application and STS keeps annoying with the message:

`Archive for required library: '/home/gtl/.m2/repository/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar' in project 'hrm' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file`

I have created the `settings.xml` and the `security-settings.xml` files under `~.m2/` and added the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    <!--    <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

I also tried to remove the `~.m2/repository/com/oracle/` directory and run `mvn clean install -U`.

```
gtl@giedi-prime ~/.m2/repository/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2 $ ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 gtl gtl  152 Nov  1 16:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 gtl gtl   22 Nov  1 16:56 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 gtl gtl 3716 Nov  1 16:56 ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 gtl gtl 3746 Nov  1 16:56 ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 gtl gtl 3733 Nov  1 16:56 ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 gtl gtl 3737 Nov  1 16:56 ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 gtl gtl  210 Nov  1 16:56 _remote.repositories
```

**EDIT** Repository entry in `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I'm lost here. How to solve this?

Comment: Jars are just Zip files. Can you open it with an archive tool (such as 7-Zip)? Maybe Maven is downloading a corrupt archive. Which repository is it loading the archive from?

Comment: @Brian, repository information added to question.

Comment: I was able to download the archive via a web browser and to open it in 7-Zip. No problems. So can you open it in an archive tool?

Comment: Thanks, buddy! I found it to be more of an Eclipse (or STS for that matter) nuisance than really a problem. I right clicked the project > Properties > Java Compiler > Building > "Configure Workspace Settings..." > opened "Build path problems" and changed the `Incomplete build path` option from Error to Warning.

Comment: @gtludwig this does not solve the problem, it just won't give you an error but the jar is still unavailable for you.

Comment: @GiladBaruchian, true

Comment: I have the same issue, I configured  maven to get the jar directly from oracle repository. It fails at tomcat startup with a ZipException.
Ican't open it with 7z.... Seem that the lib is corrupted !? really strange.
Did you find out what was the problem ?

Comment: The lib really seems to be corrupted : 
    jar -tf ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar
    java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:120)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:1115)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:293)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)